# Rails 3.0 to 3.1 Javascript error

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to learn to use Javascript in Rails and am following a Tutorial at http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3/

Even though the tutorial is written for 3.0, since Rails 3.1 is out I am using it  and running into an error.  Following the lesson to the "AJAX form submission" part where it builds a js.erb file with the following content;

```
    $('body').html("<h1><%= escape_javaScript(@post.title) %></h1>").append("<%=         escape_javaScript(@post.content) %>");
```

I am getting the following error in the server log;

```
 ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `escape_javaScript' for #<#<Class:0x00000100917048>:0x0000010084b0d8>):
1: $('body').html("<h1><%= escape_javaScript(@post.title) %></h1>").append("<%=escape_javaScript(@post.content) %>");
```

Is this a 3.0 to 3.1 conversion problem?  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you're looking for is `escape_javascript` (lower case "s"):

```
$('body').html("<h1><%= escape_javascript(@post.title) %></h1>").append("<%=         escape_javascript(@post.content) %>");
```

Ruby is case sensitive and generally uses lower case words separated by underscores for method names.

The comments for the tutorial might be worth a read:

> http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3/comment-page-1/#comment-322477

Comment: I didn't think to read the comments, thanks for pointing that out.  I guess I was getting tired when I hit this error...